# Error in double integration $\int_0^ \infty dy \int_0^ \infty e^{-2x-y} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Hello I need some help on this one...

$$
\int_0^ \infty dy \int_0^ \infty  e^{-2x-y} dx 
$$

After using substitution $t=-2x-y$, $dt = -2$ for solving the inner one I get:

$$
\int_0^ \infty \frac{1}{2}dy 
$$

Which is infinity? (and that's nonsense as this is part of another question in this case)

Wolfram Alpha says it should be $1/2$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you got from the first integral to the second?

Comment: Sorry, made a typo when writing it out

Comment: That's a little shaky, $t$ depends on $x$ **and** $y$, I recommend factoring out the $e^{-y}$ into the second integral and doing $t=-2x$ so that $dt=-2dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your integral is separable:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dy \, e^{-y} \, \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-2 x} = \frac12 $$

Answer (score 4):

In general: if you can isolate your variables in double integration, *isolate* them. In particular,
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2x-y}\text{ d}x\text{ d}y = \left(\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y}\text{ d}y\right)\left(\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2x}\text{ d}x\right)\text{.}$$
Your change of variables does not work in this case, mainly because change of variables in double integration is different from change in variables in the univariate case. See [this link](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx).

Comment: Ah, so that's it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a substitution all you have is 
$$
\int dy \int dx f(x,y) 
$$
Where $f(x,y) = h(x)g(y)$
Thus you can split the integral as
$$
\left(\int h(x) dx\right)\left(\int g(y)dy\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

As other answers suggest, you can split this into a product of two integrals.

However, your method will work as well; letting $t=-2x-y$ as you did will give

$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\left[-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x-y}\right]_{x=0}^{x=\infty}dy=\int_0^{\infty}-\frac{1}{2}\left(0-e^{-y}\right)dy=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-y}dy=\frac{1}{2}\left[-e^{-y}\right]_0^{\infty}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: The original mistake was that the switch $t=-2x-y$ didn't switch correctly the domain of the integral. It should have been $\int_0^\infty dy \int_y^{-\infty} \frac{e^t}{-2} dt=\int_0^\infty dy \int_{-\infty}^y \frac{e^t}{2} dt$ instead of $\int_0^\infty dy \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^t}{-2} dt = \int_0^\infty dy \int_0^{-\infty} \frac{e^t}{2} dt$